# Laravel 5.2 pagination + infinite scroll duplicates

Tags: laravel, pagination, duplicates, infinite-scroll

I encountered a problem with pagination in my Laravel app.
Normally, when I want to use Laravel pagination with let's say 3 rows for one page, I use Eloquent method **paginate/simplePaginate** in combination with method **latest()** like so:

```
//MyController.php
$posts= Post->latest()->paginate(3);


//MyView.blade.php
@foreach ($posts as $post)
   {{ $post->id }}
@endforeach

{{ $posts->links() }}
```

So when i have 6 posts in my database and I use Laravel pagination + Infinite scroll, that becomes:

```
6 
5   (1. page) 
4
--- ('page separator') 
3 
2   (2. page) 
1
```

But, if user inserts new row into database table before I reach page 2,
the collection shifts and second page of data becomes:

```
6 
5   (1. page) 
4
---   POST WITH ID 4 IS DUPLICATED BECAUSE OF SHIFT IN COLLECTION
4
3   (2. page) 
2
```

So, for example --- if user inserts three new rows into database before I reach paginator, then the second page will output the same three table rows as my current first page, but i'd like to output the remaining table rows:

```
6 
5   (1. page) 
4
--- AT SOME TIME BEFORE PAGINATION WAS TRIGGERED, POST WITH ID '7' HAS BEEN ADDED
3 
2   (2. page) - continues normally with remaining rows (pagination ignores newly added row)
1
```

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Use latest item's `id` in your query. you can send the latest id as page is scrolled down.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. That sounds like a good idea, but I don't know how to do that; is it possible to send some variable to Laravel controller after page load?

Comment: when you scroll-down the page, at bottom each list, you send an xhr to retrieve new items from api, with that request send the id.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand how to do that with the built in pagination function in Laravel. Do I need to write my own pagination function or can I still use Laravel's?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by asking for the first record id of the first page served

```
// {initial query} $records->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

    if(is_int($last_id)){
        $records = $records->where('id', '<=' , $last_id);
    }

    $records = $records->paginate($per_page);
```

This way, the paginator get's records starting from that id, ignoring new records

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
$posts= Post->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->distinct()
            ->paginate(3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Tried that, but didn't work, the problem persists :(

Comment: I guess, you can have a problem in your frontend part. Try to look at your pagination buttons in frontend. Possibly, your code for infinite scroll press a wrong button. You could try to use 'simple pagination' instead https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#basic-usage It displays back and forth buttons instead of number buttons.

Comment: That is when you have more than 6 rows, then your JS code for infinite scroll can work with wrong buttons in your HTML code.

Comment: Infinite scroll triggers right page button; if there is no new row added to the database, everything works fine. Only if user inserts new row before someone scrolls to second page generated by infinite scroll, the last row on first page is duplicated because of the shift of posts collection (new post is added to the top of the collection).